# which software we can use for finding out Radio blind spots؟

Tags: wireless-networking

we have two geographical points, that we want to make wireless networking for these point 
now are there any softwares to finding out Radio blind spots?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how far apart these geographic points are, I have to assume they're not line-of-sight. Otherwise, you could boost power or use a directional antenna to reduce attenuation between the two sites.

So from a technology point-of-view, there are two ways that you can approach this. You can use ArcGIS to [create an elevation profile based on a polyline](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=CDD1E6BF-1422-2418-A048-47D2ACC2C2C1) . This is an expensive solution, but if you're doing it often, it might be more precise. Precision is dependent on your data set, of course.

The alternative is free and much simpler to accomplish. Download Google Earth, and use the ruler to draw a path between two places. Then go to `Edit` -> `Show Elevation Profile`, and you'll end up with a 2D elevation chart (see image below) that you should be able to use to determine areas where line-of-sight communications will be difficult.

[image: Google Earth Elevation Profile]

Comment: now for example where are blind spots on above image?

Comment: Well that was an extreme example, going over the Himalayas. But to find deadzones you would place the ends of the line on the two locations. If the elevation between the two points is higher than either of them, WiFi signal would be interrupted. So in this example, there would no no signal between the two points, as there is elevation in the way.

Comment: so, how can we solve the problem in this situation, with increasing height of antenna or something like that? so, what's your idea for deal with deadzones?

Comment: This might be better asked as a seperate question, as the answer doesn't really fit in these comments.