# How can I find out radio blind spots from a map?

Tags: wireless-networking

I know for specifying two points on a map we should use a software like Google earth, my question is about how can I find out radio blind spots (deadzones) between two points?
I saw [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/622743/which-software-we-can-use-for-finding-out-radio-blind-spots), it was helpful for specifying and measure distance between points using Ruler tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a much more difficult question than you can immagine.  Google earth would only give you a very rough-approximation at best.  Without knowing more details about the type of signal, the type of antennas, EIRP, ... the list goes on.

There is much better tool that actually does some *science* to help calculate some more realistic estimations.  Try looking at [Radio Mobile](http://radiomobile.pe1mew.nl/).  It has been around for a very long time, and continues to get better.  I honestly do not know of a better program for doing this sort of thing.